# Creating Die Class with Virtual Functions C++

Tags: c++, function, virtual

im trying to create a C++ program Die that contains a virtual roll function which simply returns the  a number between 1 and the number of sides. I have only started the program and i have come upon a n error which i have never seen nor do i understand it at all. I think its because i have not implemented the virtual function properly or it could be how i call the virtual function in the main class? but im not sure at all and i cant figure out the solution to the problem.

Die.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class Die{
    public:
        Die();
        Die(int numSide);
        virtual int roll();
        int rollTwoDice(Die d1, Die d2); 

    private:
        int side;
};

Die::Die():side(6){}

Die::Die(int numSide):side(numSide){}

int Die::roll(){
    return rand() % side + 1;
}

int Die::rollTwoDice(Die d1, Die d2){
    return d1.roll()+d2.roll();
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include<time.h>
#include "Die.cpp"
using namespace std;

int main(){

    srand(time(NULL));  

    Die die();
    cout << die.roll;
    cout << die.roll;
    cout << die.roll;
}
```

And the error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I compiled this using g++ Die.cpp -o Die on linux commandline.

Comment: How did you compile the file?

Comment: What's the command you used to compile this...

Comment: Compile just main.cpp since u include the cppfile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to split `Die.cpp` into a header file, `Die.h`, containing the `class Die { … };` block, with the `Die.cpp` file containing all the function definitions.

Then, include all the `.cpp` files while building, so they are linked together.

```
g++ Die.cpp Main.cpp -o Die
```

Also, this line is the "most vexing parse." You cannot use the parens here:

```
Die die(); // should be Die die; (no parens)
```

Conversely, this line is missing a function call operator:

```
cout << die.roll; // should be roll(); (with parens)
```

Comment: ok, but i am getting this error: Main.cpp:1:18: error: Die.cpp: No such file or directory

Comment: @ShadowViper Never `#include` a `.cpp` file. Only header files get included. Create `Die.h` and ensure it's in the same subdirectory as the other files.